# Extend Add to cart functionality to add product variants in custom table in Sylius

Tags: sylius

I am working with Sylius 1.6 and I am trying to add product variants in a custom table as I have a separate table to store multiple order item variants. My issue is when I re-add a product's variant into the cart it's not adding. For example, I have a product with variant A. I added it into the cart. Now I am again trying to submit add to cart form by adding the same product's variant. this time the variant is not adding. I don't know how it is being added on the custom table in the first attempt. this functionality was pre-developed when I got the project so I have no idea how it is being stored the first time. I tried many ways to achieve it. I tried to override the controller but, I was getting an error that `this controller is not callable, the controller does neither exist as service nor as a class`.

**`service.yml`** here I added service for my extended `OrderItemController`

```
    sylius.controller.order_item:
    class: App\Controller\OrderItemController
    arguments: ['@templating']
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

**`_sylius.yaml`** here I defined  `OrderItemController`

```
sylius_order:
resources:
    order:
        classes:
            model: App\Entity\Order\Order
            repository: App\Repository\OrderRepository
    order_item:
        classes:
            model: App\Entity\Order\OrderItem
            controller: App\Controller\OrderItemController
```

**`OrderItemController`** here I am trying to get the request to add an item in `addAction`

```
class OrderItemController extends ResourceController
{
public function addAction(Request $request): Response
{
    die('debugging');
}
```

**`OrderItem`** Entity. Which is extended by the Sylius default `BaseOrderItem` Entity

```
                    namespace App\Entity\Order;


        use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
        use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
        use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
        use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\OrderItem as BaseOrderItem;

        /**
         * @ORM\Entity
         * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_order_item")
         * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
         */
        class OrderItem extends BaseOrderItem
        {
            /**
             * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Order\OrderItemVariants", cascade={"persist"},mappedBy="orderItem",orphanRemoval=true)
             */
            protected $orderItemVariant;


            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->orderItemVariant = new ArrayCollection();
            }

            /**
             * @ORM\PrePersist
             */
            public function prePersist()
            {
                $this->updateVariant();
            }

            /**
             * @ORM\PreUpdate
             */
            public function preUpdate()
            {
                $this->updateVariant();
            }

            public function cremoveOrder(){
                global $kernel;
                $em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('app.base_controller')->getDoctrineManager();

                $entityManager = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Order\OrderItem')->findOneBy(array('order' => $this->order->getId() ));
                if(isset($entityManager) and $entityManager->getId()){
                    $item = $em->getReference('App\Entity\Order\OrderItem', $entityManager->getId());
                    $em->remove($item);
                    $em->flush();
                    //$em->refresh($item);
                }

            }

            public function updateVariant()
            {   global $kernel;
                $em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('app.base_controller')->getDoctrineManager();
                **I tried to add the variants here but, couldn't worked for me.**
                /*foreach ($this->orderItemVariant as $variant) {
                    $orderItemVariants = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Order\OrderItemVariants')->findBy(['orderItem' => $this->getOrder()]);
                    foreach ($orderItemVariants as $variants) {
                        $this->addOrderItemVariant($variants);
                    }
                }*/
            }

            /**
             * @return Collection|OrderItemVariants[]
             */
            public function getOrderItemVariant(): Collection
            {
                return $this->orderItemVariant;
            }

            public function addOrderItemVariant(OrderItemVariants $orderItemVariant): self
            {
                if (!$this->orderItemVariant->contains($orderItemVariant)) {
                    $this->orderItemVariant[] = $orderItemVariant;
                    $orderItemVariant->setOrderItem($this);
                }

                return $this;
            }

            public function removeOrderItemVariant(OrderItemVariants $orderItemVariant): self
            {
                if ($this->orderItemVariant->contains($orderItemVariant)) {
                    $this->orderItemVariant->removeElement($orderItemVariant);
                    // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
                    if ($orderItemVariant->getOrderItem() === $this) {
                        $orderItemVariant->setOrderItem(null);
                    }
                }

                return $this;
            }


        }
```

**`OrderItemVariants`** Entity where I need to add the variants

```
            namespace App\Entity\Order;

        use App\Entity\Product\ProductVariant;
        use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

        /**
         * @ORM\Table(name="mp_order_item_variants")
         * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Order\OrderItemVariantsRepository")
         */
        class OrderItemVariants
        {
            /**
             * @ORM\Id()
             * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
             * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
             */
            protected $id;

            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Order\OrderItem", cascade={"persist"},inversedBy="orderItemVariant")
             * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_item_id", referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="CASCADE")
             */
            protected $orderItem;

            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product\ProductVariant", cascade={"persist"})
             * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="variant_id", referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="SET NULL")
             */
            protected $variant;

            /**
             *  @var int
             *  @ORM\Column(name="quantity",type="integer", nullable=true)
             */
            protected $quantity = 0;

            public function getId(): ?int
            {
                return $this->id;
            }


            public function getOrderItem(): ?OrderItem
            {
                return $this->orderItem;
            }

            public function setOrderItem(?OrderItem $orderItem): self
            {
                $this->orderItem = $orderItem;

                return $this;
            }

            public function getVariant(): ?ProductVariant
            {
                return $this->variant;
            }

            public function setVariant(?ProductVariant $variant): self
            {
                $this->variant = $variant;

                return $this;
            }

            public function getQuantity(): ?int
            {
                return $this->quantity;
            }

            public function setQuantity(?int $quantity): self
            {
                $this->quantity = $quantity;

                return $this;
            }


        }
```

How to achieve it? what is the best way to extend or override the add to cart functionality in sylius?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sorted, What I was doing wrong was adding below part in my `service.yml`

```
sylius.controller.order_item:
class: App\Controller\OrderItemController
arguments: ['@templating']
tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

I just needed to add

```
    App\Controller\OrderItemController:
    autowire: false
```

in my `service.yml` and my controller was overridden and I put my own logic to achieve what I want. I followed [this link](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/customization/controller.html) just removed step 3 and my issue resolved.